# Copy .bak file to another Windows server using job MS SQL Server agent

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to copy a .bak file nightly from Server A to Server B.
Can I do that using SQL server Job Agent to run this every night?
I am thinking of adding the copy command as a statement within a step of a job.
Something like: 'copy "G:\source\folder\"  "\target\folder\"' 
inside the step and setting the type to Operating System(CmdExec).
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

is this question about the command to copy the files?

If you want to copy entire folder use robocopy instead of copy

Answer (score 0):

You can make a SSIS package to do that, and then run it from the SQL agent.

However, don't use logical drives, such as G: -- if the server doesn't have the same mapping, it won't work.  Use the actual named servers: \serverA\source\folder to \serverB\target\folder.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes. You can try SSIS package as described [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/KeithHyer/bidn-blog/2465/copy-and-rename-a-file-in-ssis-using-the-file-system-task) or [here](http://www.rafael-salas.com/2007/03/ssis-file-system-task-move-and-rename.html). Another option is to use windows task scheduler (vs using SQL Server Agent) and a simple bat script to do the same thing.